# Unable to access login

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, hortonworks-sandbox

We have successfully installed the sandbox with a private IP under our Azure subscription. But unable to access the with the below URLs.

```
http://<hostname>.<domain.com>:4200/
http://10.xxx.xx.xx:8888/
http://<hostname>.<domain.com>:8888
```

> Network Error (tcp_error)
>
> A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
>        The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

I was however able to ssh on the host.

Comment: You may ssh to VM and check if server is listening on correct IP and port. I think it wouldn’t be listening on public IP.

Comment: This question would be better for https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** By default, Hortonworks Sandbox uses the port number 8888 is disabled, you need to open the port in order to access.

You can set the NSG rules to connect Hortonworks Sandbox registration and access.

Click on VM **(Hortonworks Sandbox)** >> **SETTINGS** >> **Network interfaces** >> **Select your Network Interface** >> **SETTINGS** >> **Network security group** >> **select your NSG** >> **Inbound security rules** >> Click on **Add** >> **Add inbound security rule (Name HDPport, Port range:8888)**>> Click **ok**

[image]

Once you set the NSG inbound rule, you're able to connect to Hortonworks Sandbox.